# MySQL query WHERE case sensitive

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following method: (Codeigniter model)

```
/**
 * Get an Ad based on its hash
 *
 * @param $hash
 * @return bool
 */
public function getAdbyHash($hash)
{
    $this->db->select('category.id as category_id, category.subcat as category_name, provinces.id as provinces_id, provinces.prov_name, users.id as users_id, users.*, ads.*');
    $this->db->where('ads.hash', $hash);

    $this->db->join('category', 'category.id = ads.subcat_id');
    $this->db->join('provinces', 'provinces.id = ads.province_id');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = ads.user_id', 'left');

    $r = $this->db->get('ads');

    //echo $this->db->last_query();

    if ($r->num_rows() == 1) {
        $ad = $r->result()[0];
        return $ad;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

And it's works fine. but today I try to hack myself introducing a similar hash in the URL, and its work too, but that's not the desired behavior.
So this hash: edit/zIpM41NkS8igFXaC must NO be the same as edit/zIpM41NkS8igFXac

Note the last char (C/c)
How do I query with case sensitive?

My approach was to use a specific method of Codeigniter and not using a direct SQL sentence. But works anyway.

Comment: Change column encoding to case sensititve? Also take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql, case sensitive compare through codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538114/mysql-case-sensitive-compare-through-codeigniter)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @ErichGarcía do you have an access to your DB? Through phpmyadmin or mysql console

Comment: @Rulisp Yes I have access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
$this->db->where('ads.hash like binary "'.$hash.'"', NULL, FALSE)
```

> **$this->db->where()** accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it
>   to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks.
>   **[CodeIgniter Doc. Where](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)**

To clean the data, you can try something like:

```
public function getAdbyHash($hash)
{
    $db = get_instance()->db->conn_id;
    $hash= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $hash);
    $this->db->select('category.id as.....'
    $this->db->where('ads.hash like binary "'.$hash.'"', NULL, FALSE);
    $this->db->join('cate......'
```

Comment: OK, this works! But, what means the second and third parameter?

Comment: String concatenation is very dangerous advice.

Comment: OK, now understand. The hash is obtained from a URL GET parameter. And I´m not protecting the field name. So, is this a risk for MySQL injection or XSS?

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is to clean $hash in the function, before the $this->db->select. I'm quite busy now, but I think I can provide an example later.

Comment: Hahaha, works perfectly, but, leave something for me, hahaha.

Answer (score 2):

As @Vixed suggested, you can modify your `where` condition.

But also, you can modify your `ads.hash` column to be case sensitive

```
ALTER TABLE `ads` MODIFY `hash` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE `utf8_bin`;
```

Note that, for Unicode, you can use only `utf8_bin` for case sensitive comparison. This is because MySQL doesn't have case-sensitive Unicode collations(see this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/137415/change-collation-of-a-mysql-table-to-utf8-general-cs))

But if your collation is `latin`, just change it to `latin_general_cs`.

Also, if you have some specific data in your column, you can take a look at this SO post - [How to change Column Collation without losing or changing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067703/how-to-change-column-collation-without-losing-or-changing-data)

**UPD. Performance notes**

Well, `like binary` looks like a very expensive operation (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097996/sql-like-binary-any-slower-than-plain-like)). Also, I think that you'll want to see this posts: [SQL 'like' vs '=' performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142235/sql-like-vs-performance) and [What effects does using a binary collation have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526334/what-effects-does-using-a-binary-collation-have)

Anyway, it requires testing

Comment: uhmmm, great tip. But, the one million question: Which solution is more optimal? I'm a newbie in MySQL, but I know that every millisecond count. Thanks!

Comment: @ErichGarcía answer updated. Testing is really required, because if you'll loose couple ms per query, it's not critical at some level. But if difference will be in dozens of ms or even greater, you should optimize your search. Once I used additional column with CRC32 hash of string for search optimization

Comment: @ErichGarcía there is no need to compare.  This is the correct solution as well as the most optimal.  Casting, coercing, and conversions in the `WHERE` clause are almost always best avoided. And using string concatenation and interpolation as shown in the other answer is an unacceptable and dangerous practice.