# col LIKE BINARY 'val%' much slower than col LIKE 'val%' . Why?

Tags: mysql, database, collation, database-indexes

I have another follow-up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685275/indexing-for-binary-like-operations-in-mysql). Although the `LIKE` pattern search (because of the collation set) uses the index and is much faster than `LIKE BINARY`, doing an explain over both of the queries seems to say that both queries use the index.

```
explain select count(*) from TransactionApp_transactions where merchantId like 'VCARD000%'

| id | select_type | table                       | type  | possible_keys                        | key                                 | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TransactionApp_transactions | range | TransactionApp_transactions_fc3e7169 | TransactionApp_transactions_fc3e7169 | 767     | NULL | 12906834 | Using where; Using index |
```

And I get the exact same `EXPLAIN` output for `explain select count(*) from TransactionApp_transactions where merchantId like binary 'VCARD000%';` (with the `rows` being a slightly smaller number)

The `key` column contains the index name for both `EXPLAIN` outputs, but the `LIKE BINARY` takes 26 seconds, compared to just 2 seconds for the simple `LIKE`.

Comment: please post the code as text and not as image

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited my question with text now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097996/sql-like-binary-any-slower-than-plain-like/8098079#8098079

can you please check this answer for once

Comment: @AshishMahajan - Yes, I understand `LIKE BINARY` doesn't use the index since the collation set is non-binary, but why does the `EXPLAIN` output say that it uses the index?

Comment: Do you have an index on `merchantId`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query using `WHERE column LIKE 'value%'` is much faster than a query using `WHERE column LIKE BINARY 'value%'` given an index on `column`.  This is entirely expected. Why?

The `LIKE 'value%'` filter uses the index to find matching rows.  It assumes the `'value%'` text to match uses the same collation as the column. And, indexes use the collation of the columns they index; the collation is baked into the index. In the scenario where the column contains case-insensitive text, this makes it possible for searches for `'value%'`, `'Value%'`, and `'VALUE%`' all to use the index even though case must be ignored in the search.

When you use `LIKE BINARY` rather than `LIKE`, you declare what collation you need for the search. You tell MySQL's query planner it cannot use the index it has, because that index's baked-in collation is not useful for your query. So it does a full table scan. That is slow.

If you want case-sensitive searches, declare a case-sensitive collation for the column when you create (or alter) the table. Then the LIKE filter will be case-sensitive.

To get a case-sensitive collation you can create the table something like this (you didn't show your table definition so this is a guess).

```
  CREATE TABLE tbl (
     ...
     mid VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin,
     ...
  )
```

or you can alter the column something like this to have a case-sensitive collation.

```
 ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY mid VARCHAR(255) COLLATE latin1_bin;
```

Remark:  `WHERE col LIKE BINARY 'value%'` is a strange way to write  a query. That may be why EXPLAIN doesn't do a good job with it.

Comment: Thanks! I would also like to know what would be an appropriate way to write the query instead of `WHERE col LIKE BINARY 'value%'`, which is what Django produces from its ORM (the ORM equivalent would be `col__startswith='value'`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the *same* collation for all of these:

- connecting to the database
- bytes in the client
- the column being tested.

Probably `merchantId` is (or _should be) `CHARACTER SET ascii`.  This may be at odds with other strings (`utf8mb4` being preferred for names, etc).

But first, how are you connecting and what is the table definition?